# Convertir string en arreglo y extraer un dato en php

Tags: javascript, php, array, javascript-objeto

Comunidad,

Necesito extraer de un arreglo JavaScript que me llega al ingresar una pagina un valor del arreglo y utilizarlo en una variable php, el arreglo en JavaScript es el siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "regularidad": "2",
        "diario": null,
        "diarioNumero": null,
        "semanaNumero": null,
        "checkDias": null,
        "mensual": 0,
        "mensualMesnum": 2,
        "mensualDianum": 2,
        "mensualOrdinario": null,
        "mensualDiaselect": null,
        "mesMensual": null,
        "anual": null,
        "anualCadanum": null,
        "anualDianum": null,
        "anualMes": null,
        "anualOrdinario": null,
        "anualOrdinariodia": null,
        "anualOrdmes": null
    }
]
```

Valide y me dicen que es complejo pasar de JavaScript a php una variable que lo mejor es pasar el arreglo como arreglo en php utilizando el explode por lo que realice lo siguiente

```
$reg = json_encode($regularidad);
$regula = explode(",", $reg);
var_dump($regula);
```

esto me arrojo el siguiente array:

```
array(18) { [0]=> string(19) "[{"regularidad":"2"" [1]=> string(13) 
""diario":null" [2]=> string(19) ""diarioNumero":null" [3]=> string(19) 
""semanaNumero":null" [4]=> string(16) ""checkDias":null" [5]=> string(11) 
""mensual":0" [6]=> string(17) ""mensualMesnum":2" [7]=> string(17) 
""mensualDianum":2" [8]=> string(23) ""mensualOrdinario":null" [9]=> string(23) 
""mensualDiaselect":null" [10]=> string(17) ""mesMensual":null" [11]=> string(12) 
""anual":null" [12]=> string(19) ""anualCadanum":null" [13]=> string(18) 
""anualDianum":null" [14]=> string(15) ""anualMes":null" [15]=> string(21) 
""anualOrdinario":null" [16]=> string(24) ""anualOrdinariodia":null" [17]=> string(20) 
""anualOrdmes":null}]" }
```

necesito extraer el valor de regularidad, que para este caso es 2, lo cual estoy realizando de la siguiente manera pero no estoy seguro si esto es practico realizarlo o puedo optimizar mi codigo:

```
$reg = json_encode($regularidad);
$datoArray = [];
$datoArray = json_decode($reg, true);
$regu = $datoArray[0]["regularidad"];
```

El resultado que me arroja es en una cadena el numero 2 que es lo que requiero, si se puede optimizar o lo estoy realizando de una manera erronea agradezco me puedan colaborar.

He realizado modificación a la pregunta puesto que lo pude resolver pero no estoy seguro que sea la mejor manera ya que utilice el decode con la propiedad de true para dejar como un arreglo regularidad pero no estoy completamente seguro si es correcto.

Quedo pendiente

Comment: No le encuentro mucho sentido a lo que estas haciendo, la variable `$regularidad` ya es un arreglo ¿porque lo convertis en `JSON` para despúes convertirlo en un arreglo?

Comment: si muestras el string seria mas facil ayudarte

Comment: @Marcos, parece que la variable viene como una cadena, desde Javascript, ese sería el sentido de querer convertirlo a JSON (seria la forma más simple de crear luego un array). No obstante, no he entendido la pregunta ni lo que se quiere extraer exactamente. Juan Carlos, pulsa en [edit] para aclarar tu problema y si es posible comparte la cadena tal y como la estás recibiendo.

Comment: Encontre una solución la plantee en la pregunta aunque no estoy seguro que sea lo mas optimo, nunca he trabajado intercambiando variables entre JavaScript y al contrario. Modifique la pregunta para aclararla un poco espero sea mas compresible la misma gracia a todos, quedo pendiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considera que en tu json tienes un arreglo de objetos,
y que los elementos del arreglo se acceden por índice
y que los atributos de objeto se acceden como tal.

```
$json = json_decode( '[
                         {
                             "regularidad": "2",
                             "diario": null,
                             "diarioNumero": null,
                             "semanaNumero": null,
                             "checkDias": null,
                             "mensual": 0,
                             "mensualMesnum": 2,
                             "mensualDianum": 2,
                             "mensualOrdinario": null,
                             "mensualDiaselect": null,
                             "mesMensual": null,
                             "anual": null,
                             "anualCadanum": null,
                             "anualDianum": null,
                             "anualMes": null,
                             "anualOrdinario": null,
                             "anualOrdinariodia": null,
                             "anualOrdmes": null
                         }
                      ]
                    '
                  );
echo $json[0]->regularidad;
```

El índice cero es para el primer y único elemento del arreglo.